# change equation label with amsmath

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, amsmath, report

I would like to change equation number from style (N) to (N.). I can do this by redefining

```
\def\@eqnnum{{\normalfont \normalcolor (\theequation.)}}
```

of the `report`:

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\@eqnnum{{\normalfont \normalcolor (\theequation.)}}                                                                                                                                               
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  a=b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

However this solution fails when I uncomment the line

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

How to solve?

Comment: Should references to equations also have a dot?

Comment: @Bernard, yes, how to add the dot to references?

Comment: I guess @Joule's solution does it automatically. What' not so automatic is to have a dot in the tag, but not  in the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\def\theequation{  \ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter\fi \@arabic\c@equation.}
\makeatother
```